# preg_replace not working? PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Why does this no replace all commas with @ except the one in 'location, state'?

```
$test = preg_replace("#([^ ])([,])([^ ])#","$1@$3","100,,,'test','two',,'location, state',,[],1")
```

Expected: 100@@@'test'@'two'@@'location, state'@@[]@1

Actual: 100@,,'test'@'two'@,'location, state'@,[]@1

I think it is because the consecutive commas are matched in the pattern, how do i get it to continue from the start of the matched character to include all commas?

Comment: What are your current result and your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:

```
preg_replace('/(?<!\s),(?!\s)/', '@', "100,,,'test','two',,'location, state',,[],1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the string that have been matched before will not get matched again during a single run of preg_replace. So the first replace is this:

```
10(0)(,)(,),'test'  => 100@,,'test'
                            ^
```

Now the marked character is the first one that preg_replace is allowed to match -> it will also not be replaced, because there is nothing to be matched by the first `([^ ])`.

What you are looking for are [look-ahead and look-behind assertions:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

```
preg_replace("#(?<=[^ ])([,])(?=[^ ])#", "@", …)
```